# Javascript/jQuery SetInterval inside SetInterval show duplicate data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with `setInterval`. Now it will be `setInterval` inside `setInterval`.
Below is the sample code working but for `demo2` it show me duplicate data.

For `var services` must and always run. But for `tempJob1` or another tempJob can be stop by using `clearInterval(tempJob1)`

```js
var services = setInterval(function () {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "Hello";
    
    //can be tempJob1, tempJob2, tempJob3, etc...
    var tempJob1 = setInterval(function () {
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML += "Hello";
    }, 1000);
    
    //clearInterval(tempJob1)
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
<div id="demo2"></div>
```

My question is, how to prevent it show duplicate data on `demo2`?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi, `demo2` should show text `Hello` one by one, but now it's show duplicate.

Comment: What determines ***when*** tempJob2 is supposed to fire?

Comment: So you want it to do the same as services, but 1 second later?

Comment: @Nick yes correct

Comment: I'm not sure what problem you're actually trying to solve but I'm pretty sure this isn't the solution. It sounds like what you actually want is a "run this first thing and after it's done run another different thing **n** millis later" where The Thing and **n** may vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because every time `services` repeats its call cycle `tempJob1` is recreated and that causes multiple instances of `tempJob1` calling at the same time you can fix it by checking and creating only 1 `tempJob1` :

```js
var tempJob1 
var services = setInterval(function () {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "Hello";
    
    //can be tempJob1, tempJob2, tempJob3, etc...
    if (!tempJob1)
      tempJob1 = setInterval(function () {
          document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML += "Hello";
      }, 1000);
    
    //clearInterval(tempJob1)
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
<div id="demo2"></div>
```

Comment: Hi `tempJob1` should be inside of `setInterval`. Is it possible?

Comment: no you have to create a variable to make sure it is accessible